# Joins in the Firebase Database with Polymer Properties

Tags: javascript, join, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer

[**GOOD SOLUTION HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353453/6213524)

In the case below I am trying to get data from one location and then find the related data in a different location [(the firebase joins)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idu9EJPSxiY&index=5&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).
I am able to retrieve the appropriate data and display in the my console but I kind of stuck when it comes to storing them in one of my properties to then loop over them with a dom-repeat template. In addition I am not entirely sure if this should be done with plane JavaScript or the PolymerFire components.

```
      //Key value for a course that I retrieved from a URL Query
      var ckey = KSH456YU789;

      //Get the Videos that belong to that course key
      firebase.database().ref('/courseVideos/' + ckey).on('child_added', snap => {

        //Get the video data of each video that belongs to the course
        let videoRef = firebase.database().ref('videos/' + snap.key);
        videoRef.once('value', function(snapShot) {
          this.set('courseVidObj', snapShot.val());
          //console.log() the data works
          console.log(this.courseVidObj);
        }.bind(this));

      });
```

As it can be seen above I am able to log the data that is stored in my property 'courseVidData' which is from type Array. However, this is run for each request which basically overwrites the previous stored value.
This makes it impossible to use my property inside a dom-repeat template. As shown below:

```
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[courseVidData]]" as="vid">

    <my-card
      card-img="[[vid.img]]"
      card-name="[[vid.title]]"
      card-text="[[vid.description]]"
      card-key="[[vid.$key]]">
    </my-card>

  </template>
```

**Second Attempt**
In my second attempt I used a forEach() to store the returned data insie an array which I then added to my 'courseVidData' property.
This returns me as expected an array with three objects. Unfortunately the dom-repeat is doing nothing.

```
       firebase.database().ref('/courseVideos/' + ckey).once('value', function(snap) {
        var vidData = [];
        snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          let videoRef = firebase.database().ref('videos/' + childSnapshot.key);
          videoRef.once('value', function(snapShot) {
          vidData.push(snapShot.val());
          this.courseVidData = vidData;
          console.log(this.courseVidData); //returns array with the object's
          }.bind(this));
        });
      });
```

Comment: In your first attempt, you didn't show how you update `courseVidData` (only show in code is `courseVidObj`) so It can't tell much. In your second attempt, plain javascript `vidData.push` won't work, you should use [push](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-push) instead.

Comment: Thanks @user2438933 was reading through the documentation and found my mistake as explained below. Would be nice if you could accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way of doing it after reading through the documentation of the Polymer [Template repeater (dom-repeat)](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat) And the way Arrays are handled in Polymer.
This might be not the cleanest approach but it works for now. If somebody is pointing out what could be improved I am happy to change my answer or accept a different one.

```
      //Retrieve course videos and their details
      firebase.database().ref('/courseVideos/' + ckey).on('child_added', snap => {
        let videoRef = firebase.database().ref('videos/' + snap.key);
        videoRef.once('value', function(snapShot) {

          if (!this.courseVidData) this.set('courseVidData', []);
          this.push('courseVidData', {video: snapShot.val()});

        }.bind(this));
      });
```

I can't really explain why but I had to add a if statement to check for the array and set it if not existing. Then I place the value of my snapshot inside the 'courseVidData' Property which is declared inside my Properties and from type Array.
Because the key of each returned object is now 'video' it is necessary to use [[item.video.title]] to access the object values (code below).

```
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[courseVidData]]">

       <h1>[[index]]</h1>
       <h1>[[item.video.title]]</h1>

      </template>
```

**Update**
Although this method works the unique key Firebase creates gets lost in the array. To keep the key for each object I store both key and object inside another object and append this to my array.
I know this isn't pretty and as mentioned above I am still looking for a better solution. However, it does the trick for me as a bloody beginner.

```
       firebase.database().ref('/courseVideos/' + ckey).on('child_added', snap => {
         let videoRef = firebase.database().ref('videos/' + snap.key);
         videoRef.once('value', function(snapShot) {
           var vidKeyObj = {key:snapShot.key, value:snapShot.val()};
           if (!this.courseVidData) this.set('courseVidData', []);
           this.push('courseVidData', {video: vidKeyObj});
       }.bind(this));
```